# Improper integral comparison test of $\int _{1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^2\ln\left(x+1\right)}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can I find an integral to compare to $$\int _1^{\infty \:\:}\frac{dx}{x^2 \ln\left(x+1\right)}$$ so I can determine the convergency/divergency of the integral?

I tried to compare to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ but I get the wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

For all $x > e-1$, $\ln(1 + x) > 1$, so you can compare to $1/x^2$ to find convergence.

Comment: Sorry but I made I typo, it has to be from 1 to infinity

Comment: @Savantik now changed to reflect that.

Comment: Wait, I can change the bounds from 1 to e-1?

Comment: @Savantik Split the integral into $\int_1^{e-1}$ and $\int_{e-1}^\infty$. $\int_1^{e-1}dx/(x^2\ln(1+x))$ is an integral of a bounded function over a bounded interval, and thus is obviously finite. Then you check the $\int_{e-1}^\infty$ for convergence.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: In the infinity, the expression under the integral is less than $1/x^2$, so the integral is convergent.

Comment: I'm sorry it should've been from 1 to infinity!

Comment: @Savantik So we have only the first part. :-) I have just removed the second one.

Comment: Yes, but one thing, the expression is only less than 1/x² starting from x=1.718 (I checked with desmos) so I'm not really sure

Comment: @Savantik For checking convergence we need only check the behaviour for large numbers. The integral, say, $\int_1^2$ is the Riemann integral of a continuous bounded function, so finite.

Answer (score 1):

Define,
\begin{align*}f:\left[1,+\infty\right[&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\x&\longmapsto \frac{1}{x^{2}\ln(x+1)}\end{align*}

The improper integral of $f$ over $[1,+\infty[$ conveges if
$$\underbrace{\int_{1}^{\varepsilon}f(x)\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{1}}+\underbrace{\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}f(x)\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{2};\text{near}+\infty}$$ for a natural number $\varepsilon >1$ they're convergent integrals.

1. The function $f$ is continuous over the bounded and closed interval $[1,\varepsilon]$ hence $I_{1}$ there exists and it's finite, hence convergent.
2. We have $\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln(x+1)}\underset{+\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln x}$ because $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln(x+1)}}{ \frac{1}{x^{2}\ln(x)}}=1$ and both functions are non-negatives over $[\varepsilon,+\infty[$. So $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}f(x)\, {\rm d}x$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln x}\, {\rm d}x$ converges which clearly converges as pointed out in the other answer. Alternatively, notice that $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln x}\, {\rm d}x$ converges  if and only if $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geqslant \varepsilon}\frac{1}{k^{2}\ln n}$ converges and the convergence is follows of Cauchy's condensation theorem. Hence $I_{2}$ converges.

Therefore,
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln(x+1)}\, {\rm d}x$$ converges.